# What is difference between C library and Standard Library?

Tags: c

I just want to know what is the difference between C library and standard library?
main() is an user defined  function but the name "main" and it arguments are predefined in in C library or standard library ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Erm... no?!?

The function `main` and its arguments are defined by the C *language* standard. This has nothing to do with any library; it's always up to you to implement that function.

In common lingo, a "C library" is any function library that has a C interface, i.e. is usable by C programs.

The "C standard library", "standard C library" or "standard library" is the library containing the functions defined by chapter 7 of the C language standard. This includes (but is not limited to) the functions declared in the headers `<stdio.h>`, `<string.h>`, `<stdlib.h>` etc. etc.

The "standard library" for Linux, for example, is the GNU C library, or glibc. In addition to the functions from chapter 7 of the language standard, glibc contains many *additional* functions *not* defined there. This makes things a bit fuzzy. Those additional functions are part of glibc, but not part of the "C standard library".

You know, all bulldogs are dogs, but not all dogs are bulldogs. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

LIBRARY FUNCTION:
*library function are predefined set of function that are defined in c library.
*user can only use the functions, but cannot change or modify the functions.

USER DEFINED FUNCTION:
*user defined function are function defined by the user according to his/her representation.
*user can use and modify this function.